# Cant display full screen image background

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8mjy.png)I am trying to display a full background image on my vue component, but i cant figure out why my image doesnt fill the full screen here is the code :

```
<template>
<div class="BG">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="exampleInputEmail1"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              id="exampleInputPassword1"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>



<style scoped>
.BG{
  background: url(../assets/BG2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

do you know what i am missing ?

Comment: Is the component a route? or a component rendered inside another one, because if it's the latter, the styling of the parent might interfere

Comment: No its a route , its my login component wich has his own route

Comment: Can you add an image to the question, so that we can see how it looks for now?

Comment: Have you applied `body {margin: 0;}` ?

Comment: I edited my question and there is a link to an image that show the thing @Paul-LouisMas

Answer (score 0):

It's because the container is not at 100% height,
html and body should be 100% height (even for your wrapper class "BG"), otherwise the height will be defined by its content.

Comment: so i just have to set height property to 100% on my .BG{} or even on my container ?

Comment: If it does something like html > body > div (with class BG): html, body and bg should have 100% height. If your div (with class BG) have another container than body, you should make it 100% height too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using some sort of `router-view` to display the route, but the body also contains a navbar (as seen in the picture). You would need to use some sort of layout or meta data associated to the route to let the main layout page change the background-image accordingly.

Kinda like used [here](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/dynamic-vue-layout-components/) so that you can define the background-image from the layout.